# fn: functions in XPathExpressions cause Exceptions in JDK1.6

Tags: java, function, xpath

I would like to select the value of the first "href" attribute from documents like this using XPath:

```
<div>
  <a href="#a">
    <span>foo</span>
  </a>

  <a href="#b">
    <span>bar</span>
  </a>

  <a href="#c">
    <span>baz</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

However, I am only interested in those `a` elements that govern spans with text content "bar" or "baz". I was hoping that I could achieve that with the following Java code:

```
Document document = getDocument(); // returns non-null Document

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String href = xpath.evaluate("//a[fn:matches(span, '^ba.$')]/attribute::href", document);
```

but whenever I'm using one of the `fn:` functions in an XPathExpression, I get

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unknown error in XPath.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(XPath.java:363)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(XPath.java:301)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(XPathImpl.java:210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:275)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:365)
    at MyCode(MyCode.java:71)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.functions.FuncExtFunction.execute(FuncExtFunction.java:206)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.PredicatedNodeTest.executePredicates(PredicatedNodeTest.java:340)
[...]
```

Similar Exceptions are thrown when I use `fn:starts-with`. I'm using JDK 1.6 on GNU/Linux.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the core xpath functions 1.0 (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#corelib) are supported by default (as stated here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFunctionResolver.html).

Therefore, instead of `matches` you should use `contains` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains).

Answer (score 4):

These string functions are available in XPath 2.0 which is not supported by the Java XPath API. You will have to use another library like [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) for evaluating XPath 2.0 expressions:

Answer (score 1):

First, if you use a prefix (`fn`) you should bind that to a namespace URI.

Second, **XPath 1.0 functions doesn't use a prefix binding**. That would be interpreted as a extension function call.

Third, `match()` is a XPath 2.0 function.

In XPath 1.0, this expression should work:

```
/div/a[span[starts-with(.,'ba')]][1]/@href
```

If you use `//` step operator, you should use:

```
(//a[span[starts-with(.,'ba')]])[1]/@href
```